# Mysql how to get the records from tableA that dont appear in tableB

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i need help on how to get the intersection of two tables in mysql

TABLE A
Col-a
Col-b

TABLE B
Col-a
Col-b

I need all the values in table B that are not in table A
I don't want to use NOT IN because it seems to take over 30 minutes :|
Table A has 35000 records
Table B has 36128 records (but table b is a VIEW from an inner join)
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Do you have indexes on those columns? that really isn't a lot of records, unless you've done something like a cross join which would indeed take a lot of time.

Comment: Which of those columns are nullable?

Answer (score 0):

According to the picture shown [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins), I'd suggest this *right join*:

```
select b.* 
  from table_a a 
 right join table_b b 
    on a.col_a=b.col_a and a.col_b=b.col_b
 where a.col_a is null;
```

Edit: I updated the statement so that now two columns are used for comparision.